# Unable to view more than 1 million records in csv file when exported through Dataloder CLI

Tags: data-loader

I am trying to export data from Salesforce through dataloader command line interface. I have integrated dataloader command line interface with ANT for extracting records. When i try to extract more than 1 million rows, i am unable to view the csv file with more than 1 million records. Kindly suggest an alternative.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean "unable to open csv" ?

Comment: would rephrase my question then -- what do you mean by "unable to open"?

Comment: are you trying to open with Excel? with Notepad++ ? with what?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit in csv to open more than 1 million.

My suggestion would be to split the exporting based on some condition so that you wouldnt cross 1million.

Comment: Please use the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757991/maximum-number-of-rows-of-csv-data-in-excel-sheet as refernce

Comment: note: limit of csv file in case if that is being opened by excel, not limit to the csv file itself

Answer (score 0):

We are using dataloader as well to extract more than one million record reports from sfdc into csv files. We are using MS Access to process the data afterwards without any problem. You just have to import the csv into Access and it will show all the rows.

Cheers,
Krisz